# I can't use an item in another screen in React Native

Tags: react-native, native

I'm trying to use a selected element from a dropdown in another screen, but when I access the other screen where I expect the selected element to be rendered, it gives me undefined:

This is the screen (Screen1) where I select the item:

```
<TouchableOpacity
onPress={() => {
navigation.navigate('Screen2', { fieldName: selectedField.name });
}}
>
```

I want after clicking to navigate to the other screen and display the selectedField.name value there.

Here is the other screen - Screen2:

```
const Screen2 = ({ route }) => {
const navigation = useNavigation();
const { params } = route;
const fieldName = params.fieldName;
console.log('Params:', params);
return (
<View>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
    Selected field: {fieldName}
  </Text>
  <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back" color="#662044" />
</View>
);
};
```

I get the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fieldName' of undefined"
In Screen1 through console log I get the value of the selected field successfully, but in Screen2 it doesn't work - gives me that the parameter is undefined

I can't use an item in another screen in React Native

Comment: Can you create a slack link and share so others can help more efficiently. Or else, share more details. e.g. can you tell where the selected field is defined

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by updating your `Screen2` like below:

```
import { useRoute } from "@react-navigation/native";

const Screen2 = () => {
const route = useRoute();
const navigation = useNavigation();

return (
<View>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
    Selected field: {route.params.fieldName}
  </Text>
  <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back" color="#662044" />
</View>
);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `useRoute` hook instead of passed parameter, here is an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/pass-params-react-navigation)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details', {fieldName: '123!1'})}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen() {
  const route = useRoute()
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Text>{route.params.fieldName}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```